# How to make Spark use all the cores?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have been using spark-1.4.1 on Ubuntu AWS Box with 64GB RAM and 36 Cores. There is a text file of size 965MB with 17mn lines in it. I am loading it in memory and mapping the rdd using spark like this:

```
def clean(line):
       line = line.strip().replace("'","").split('\t')
       return (line[0], int(line[1]))


data = sc.parallelize(open('data.tsv')).map(lambda x: clean(x)).groupByKey()
```

Two things:
I expect Spark to use all of the cores available in my machine which is 36 in number but I see there is only one CPU being utilized all the time. (I found that out using htop) How can I make it to use all the CPUs.

Because it is not using all the CPUs probably that is the reason that it is not able to process 17mn lines. It is giving me this error:
[image]

Comment: 1) Please don't ask two questions at once :) 2) Without seeing your config, number of partitions in the rdd and cluster manager it is hard to say why Spark doesn't utilize all cores  3) Index out of bounds suggest rather some malformed lines which are not properly processed by `clean` function.  So `#process the line` is most likely important 4) Stack trace as a text is __much__ better than screenshot.

Comment: Agree about 1 but I thought both might be related. I will check 3 again. about 2: This is a standalone spark application. There are no nodes. How can I view the configs?

Comment: Why `open('data.tsv')` instead of `sc.textFile()`???

Comment: Didn't realize that is an option. Thanks for bringing that to my notice. Will that make a difference?

Comment: Generally speaking it will. `parallelize` reads data locally and distributes to workers, `textFile` reads data in parallel on each worker.  Regarding config you can start with  `sc._conf.getAll()`. And please code you provide complete `clean` code?

Comment: Could you replace your `clean` function with below and see if second problem persists: 
`def clean(line):
    line = line.strip().replace("'","").split('\t')
    try:
        return (line[0], int(line[1]))
    except IndexError as e:
        return (None, None)`